# How to get the name of a query from a `gql` object?

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-tag

I use `gql` from [graphql-tag](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag).
Let's say I have a `gql` object defined like this:

```
const QUERY_ACCOUNT_INFO = gql`
  query AccountInfo {
    viewer {
      lastname
      firstname
      email
      phone
      id
    }
  }
`
```

There must be a way to get `AccountInfo` from it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using Apollo there is also the explicit `getOperationName` which seems to be rather undocumented but has worked for all my usecases.

```
import { getOperationName } from "@apollo/client/utilities";

export const AdminListItemsDocument = gql`
  query AdminListItems(
    $first: Int
    $after: String
    $before: String
    $last: Int
  ) {
    items(
      first: $first
      after: $after
      before: $before
      last: $last
    ) {
      nodes {
        id
        name
      }
      totalCount
      pageInfo {
        hasPreviousPage
        hasNextPage
        startCursor
        endCursor
      }
    }
  }
`;

getOperationName(AdminListBlockLanguagesDocument); // => "AdminListItems"
```

Comment: How can I get `items` from above query?

Answer (score 11):

What's returned by `gql` is a [DocumentNode](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/language/ast.js#L193) object. A GraphQL document could include multiple definitions, but assuming it only has the one and it's an operation, you can just do:

```
const operation = doc.definitions[0]
const operationName = operation && operation.name
```

If we allow there may be fragments, we probably want to do:

```
const operation = doc.definitions.find((def) => def.kind === 'OperationDefinition')
const operationName = operation && operation.name
```

Keep in mind it's technically possible for multiple operations to exist in the same document, but if you're running this client-side against your own code that fact may be irrelevant.

The core library also provides a utility function:

```
const { getOperationAST } = require('graphql')
const operation = getOperationAST(doc)
const operationName = operation && operation.name
```

Comment: If I use getOperationAST I get the typescript error: Expected 2 arguments but got 1.

Comment: If I use the operation = doc.definition[0] ... way then I get typescript error Property 'name' does not exist on type 'DefinitionNode'

Comment: Side question: how to do the same with a fragment? The question is different but googling led me here

Comment: If I have `x = gql' query MyFakeName ($var: var) { realName (var: $var) { someField } } '`, then I get `x.definitions[0].name.value = MyFakeName`. How do I get `realName` ?

Comment: @Juan Perez `x.definitions[0].selectionSet.selections[0].name.value` -> `realName`